# Django with Postgresql, column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using Django 1.11 and Postgresql 9.6
In my app, there is a model called Person, it have several fields. In database, it's a materialized view.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    personid = models.CharField(max_length=18, primary_key=True)
    count = models.BigIntegerField()
    native = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    ...
```

When execute

```
persons = Person.objects.values('personid', 'native')\
    .annotate(total=Count('native'))
```

It says `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "person.native" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

When only **select one column** or **not set the personid as primary key** or **not execute annotate** it won't get error.

I print the query sql:

```
SELECT
"person"."native",
"person"."personid",
COUNT("person"."native") AS "total"
FROM "person"
GROUP BY "person"."native", "person"."personid"
```

What can I do?

I make the view into table and set the personid as primary key, and then no problems.

Comment: What happens when you try this query in the `psql` shell (or any other interface that let's you issue the query directly), without any django or python?

Comment: In psql shell, it works. So I don't know why.

Comment: Can you rule out that Django sends other SQL than the one it prints to the database?

Comment: Yes, I print it and execute it.

Comment: `personid` is the primary key. It won't have any effect if you group by this field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known bug in Django >= 1.8 and Django < 2.0.  It has been fixed in Django 2.0.  I had the same problem and brought it up in the django-users mailing list.

What happened is that Django performed some optimizations, especially based on PostgreSQL.  In PostgreSQL, you only need to use the pk columns in the GROUP BY clause, but that is only for tables.  (The query runs more quickly if you do that.)  You cannot have a PK in a view in PostgreSQL, which is why it is a problem for us since we are using un-managed models coupled with views in the backend.

References:

- https://github.com/django/django/commit/daf2bd3efe53cbfc1c9fd00222b8315708023792
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/lx3ZSq-W9X4
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/lx3ZSq-W9X4/yh4I2CsoBwAJ
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28107

Answer (score 0):

*My django's version is 2.2.10.*
I met the problem and I solved it.
you should add the `.order_by("xxx")` follow your ORM!

**Before**(Error with `must appear in the GROUP BY clause`):

```
search_models.Author.objects.values("first_institution", 'institution_code').annotate(counts=Count('first_institution'))
```

**After**(Fixed):

```
search_models.Author.objects.values("first_institution", 'institution_code').annotate(counts=Count('first_institution')).order_by('-counts')
```

It's worked for me, also wish can help you.