# Django ProgrammingError must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: python, django, postgresql, group-by

Give it any basic model say;

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(_('Content html'), max_length=65000)
    author = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

A query like `Post.objects.annotate(Count('id'))` (or any field, any annotate()) fails with the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "post.created" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "post"."id", "post"."created", "post"."ti...
```

Using django 1.11.16, and postgres 9.4.19.

As I read here in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584527/django-with-postgresql-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in) tried different django versions and postgres versions; using django 2.0, 2.1.2, postgres 9.5.. same error! Reading around I've seen that might be a problem related to SQL, but I'm having this problem only at one server running Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic). Running the query locally at Ubuntu 16.04, with django 1.11.16, or **any** version above that and postgres 9.4 or above runs fine in my local system.. So the problem might actually be related with some low level libraries perhaps, I'm not running complex queries, any simple annotate() with django 1.11+ fails in ubuntu 18.04 with postgres 9.4 or 9.5

**[UPDATE]**
**Might be useful for you if you find yourself in this scenario with no clues of what's going on, verify that the table in question has its indexes created**. My problem turned out to be the `posts` table had no `PRIMARY KEY` definition nor any other constraint, a fail in a `pg_restore` which restored all the data and **some** schema definitions, yeah you read right **some other schema definitions were missing**, no idea of why.. But instead of trying to debug what happened with `pg_restore` in the first place, I ran an initial `python manage migrate` on an empty DB so the schema was correctly created this time and verified (`psql -d <db_name> -c '\d posts'`), then run `pg_restore` again with the `--data-only` and `--disable-triggers` flags.. So finally I got the schema and data properly restored and the query worked

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(Post.objects.annotate(Count('id')).query)`? That will be the sql query from your queryset.

Comment: It makes not much sense to count `id`s when *annotating*, since every row contains *one* record, and hence the count is *always* 1 (or `0` in case of a `NULL`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: That's true. But it doesn't explain why they get this SQL error.

Comment: So the conclusion in the question you linked is that this bug is specific to models backed by a database view instead of a database table. If you only get this bug in your production database, you should investigate the db schema and look for any differences between the production db and the development db.

Comment: Hey guys, I'll update my question here; Yeah as far as I understand for now, the GROUP BY only ID without referencing the other fields of the SELECT works if you actually have an index on ID.. turns out to be that after a pg_restore for some weird reason (that I failed to uncover) the data was restored but *some* (not all) schema definitions were missing.. so the posts table for instance had no PRIMARY KEY statement, and thus that annotate fails

Comment: The [UPDATE] worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

That error message is because PostgreSQL will not make a guess as to what to do with non-grouped columns when there's a aggregate function in the query. This is one of the cases where the Django ORM handwaves too much and allows us to shoot ourselves in the foot.

I ran a test on my projects that use Django 2.1 and another that uses 1.11 with `Model.objects.annotate(Count('id'))` with no issues. If you post the full QuerySet, people will be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks @schillingt ! Yeah sometimes having too much magic in an abstraction layer makes it complicated to debug in corner cases :/
I figured what was the problem, the table had no schema when restoring a dump with pg_restore, the data was there but the table had no indexes, no constraints, primary keys.. That was the problem causing the query to fail here, why pg_restore failed to restore the schema of some* (not all) tables.. no idea.. Devised a workaround and went that way before trying to debug pg_restore

Answer (score 2):

I met the problem and I solved it.
you should add the `.order_by("xxx")` follow your ORM!

before:

```py
search_models.Author.objects.values("first_institution", "institution_code").annotate(
    counts=Count("first_institution")
)
```

after:

```py
search_models.Author.objects.values("first_institution", "institution_code").annotate(
    counts=Count("first_institution")
).order_by("-counts")
```

It's worked for me, also wish can help you.